# html select coming twice while calling .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

trying to generate some dynamic div html content. I used `var content = $('#dynamicAddRow0').html();` for getting the div content.
I am getting the div content, the problem is in that div content select tag is coming twice. Below is my code

```
 <div id="dynamicAddRow0">
     <div class="clear-block">
                      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group cc">
                          <label for="reToSeperate" id="test">From</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 no-padding">
                            <form:select  class="selectpicker" path="hraList[0].fromMonth">
                            <option value=""><c:out value="Select"></c:out></option>
                            <c:forEach items="${monthsList}" var="commute">
                              <option value="${commute}"><c:out value="${commute}"></c:out></option>
                              </c:forEach>
                            </form:select>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 no-right-pad">
                            <form:select class="selectpicker" path="hraList[0].fromYear" required="required">
                            <option value=""><c:out value="Select"></c:out></option>
                              <c:forEach items="${yearsList}" var="commute">
                              <option>  <c:out value="${commute}"></c:out></option>
                              </c:forEach>
                            </form:select>
                          </div>

                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group cc">
                          <label for="reToSeperate">To</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 no-padding">
                            <form:select class="selectpicker" path="hraList[0].toMonth" required="required">
                            <option value=""><c:out value="Select"></c:out></option>
                             <c:forEach items="${monthsList}" var="commute">
                              <option><c:out value="${commute}"></c:out></option>
                              </c:forEach>
                            </form:select>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 no-right-pad">
                            <form:select class="selectpicker" path="hraList[0].toYear" required="required">
                            <option value=""><c:out value="Select"></c:out></option>
                              <c:forEach items="${yearsList}" var="commute">
                              <option><c:out value="${commute}"></c:out></option>
                              </c:forEach>
                            </form:select>

                          </div>

                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

When i run `$('#dynamicAddRow0').html()` in console i am getting the below output:

```
<div class="clear-block">
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group cc">
         <label id="test" for="reToSeperate">From</label>
         <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 no-padding">
            <select id="hraList0.fromMonth" name="hraList[0].fromMonth" class="selectpicker" style="display: none;" disabled="disabled">
               <option value="">Select</option>
               <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
               <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
               <option value="Mar">Mar</option>
               <option value="Apr">Apr</option>
               <option value="May">May</option>
               <option value="Jun">Jun</option>
               <option value="Jul">Jul</option>
               <option value="Aug">Aug</option>
               <option value="Sep">Sep</option>
               <option value="Oct">Oct</option>
               <option value="Nov">Nov</option>
               <option value="Dec">Dec</option>
               <option value=""></option>
            </select>
            <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select">
               <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle selectpicker btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="hraList0.fromMonth" title="Jan" value="" disabled="disabled"><span class="filter-option pull-left">Jan</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></button>
               <div class="dropdown-menu open">
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu inner selectpicker" role="menu">
                     <li data-original-index="0"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Select</span>"><span class="text">Select</span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                     <li data-original-index="1" class="selected"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Jan</span>"><span class="text">Jan</span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                     <li data-original-index="2"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Feb</span>"><span class="text">Feb</span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                     <li data-original-index="3"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Mar</span>"><span class="text">Mar</span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                     <li data-original-index="4"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Apr</span>"><span class="text">Apr</span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                     <li data-original-index="5"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>May</span>"><span class="text">May</span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                     <li data-original-index="6"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Jun</span>"><span class="text">Jun</span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                     <li data-original-index="7"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Jul</span>"><span class="text">Jul</span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                     <li data-original-index="8"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Aug</span>"><span class="text">Aug</span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                     <li data-original-index="9"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Sep</span>"><span class="text">Sep</span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                     <li data-original-index="10"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Oct</span>"><span class="text">Oct</span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                     <li data-original-index="11"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Nov</span>"><span class="text">Nov</span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                     <li data-original-index="12"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Dec</span>"><span class="text">Dec</span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                     <li data-original-index="13"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;></span>"><span class="text"></span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 no-right-pad">
            <select id="hraList0.fromYear" name="hraList[0].fromYear" class="selectpicker" required="required" aria-required="true" style="display: none;" disabled="disabled">
               <option value="">Select</option>
               <option>2017</option>
               <option>2018</option>
            </select>
            <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select">
               <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle selectpicker btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="hraList0.fromYear" title="2017" value="" disabled="disabled"><span class="filter-option pull-left">2017</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></button>
               <div class="dropdown-menu open">
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu inner selectpicker" role="menu">
                     <li data-original-index="0"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Select</span>"><span class="text">Select</span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                     <li data-original-index="1" class="selected"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>2017</span>"><span class="text">2017</span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                     <li data-original-index="2"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>2018</span>"><span class="text">2018</span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group cc">
         <label for="reToSeperate">To</label>
         <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 no-padding">
            <select id="hraList0.toMonth" name="hraList[0].toMonth" class="selectpicker" required="required" aria-required="true" style="display: none;" disabled="disabled">
               <option value="">Select</option>
               <option>Jan</option>
               <option>Feb</option>
               <option>Mar</option>
               <option>Apr</option>
               <option>May</option>
               <option>Jun</option>
               <option>Jul</option>
               <option>Aug</option>
               <option>Sep</option>
               <option>Oct</option>
               <option>Nov</option>
               <option>Dec</option>
               <option></option>
            </select>
            <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select">
               <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle selectpicker btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="hraList0.toMonth" title="Aug" value="" disabled="disabled"><span class="filter-option pull-left">Aug</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></button>
               <div class="dropdown-menu open">
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu inner selectpicker" role="menu">
                     <li data-original-index="0"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Select</span>"><span class="text">Select</span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                     <li data-original-index="1"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Jan</span>"><span class="text">Jan</span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                     <li data-original-index="2"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Feb</span>"><span class="text">Feb</span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                     <li data-original-index="3"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Mar</span>"><span class="text">Mar</span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                     <li data-original-index="4"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Apr</span>"><span class="text">Apr</span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                     <li data-original-index="5"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>May</span>"><span class="text">May</span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                     <li data-original-index="6"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Jun</span>"><span class="text">Jun</span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                     <li data-original-index="7"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Jul</span>"><span class="text">Jul</span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                     <li data-original-index="8" class="selected"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Aug</span>"><span class="text">Aug</span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                     <li data-original-index="9"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Sep</span>"><span class="text">Sep</span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                     <li data-original-index="10"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Oct</span>"><span class="text">Oct</span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                     <li data-original-index="11"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Nov</span>"><span class="text">Nov</span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                     <li data-original-index="12"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Dec</span>"><span class="text">Dec</span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                     <li data-original-index="13"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;></span>"><span class="text"></span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 no-right-pad">
            <select id="hraList0.toYear" name="hraList[0].toYear" class="selectpicker" required="required" aria-required="true" style="display: none;" disabled="disabled">
               <option value="">Select</option>
               <option>2017</option>
               <option>2018</option>
            </select>
            <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select">
               <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle selectpicker btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="hraList0.toYear" title="2017" value="" disabled="disabled"><span class="filter-option pull-left">2017</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></button>
               <div class="dropdown-menu open">
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu inner selectpicker" role="menu">
                     <li data-original-index="0"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Select</span>"><span class="text">Select</span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                     <li data-original-index="1" class="selected"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>2017</span>"><span class="text">2017</span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                     <li data-original-index="2"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>2018</span>"><span class="text">2018</span><span class="glyphicon undefined check-mark"></span></a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am not understanding why that second select tag is coming and which is not selectable. Kindly help me how to resolve this.
Thanks in-advance.

Comment: It looks like you're using something to generate your actual HTML.  Is it wrapped in a loop construct of some kind?  Forgetting jQuery for a moment, when you manually view the page source in your browser, what do you see?  The JavaScript code is only going to be aware of what's actually sent to the browser, not whatever code generated it.

Comment: are you positive you're getting unique ids on your dynamically generated rows?

Comment: @RobertWade After getting the content i am putting the content into new div like below:
content = "<div id='dynamicAddRow"+index+"'>"+content+"</div>";

Comment: @David actually i have an form which contains some fields when user clicks on Add another form same form content i have to show that is working when he filled the two forms and submitted, while fetching one form is default in the UI if user has two forms i have to generate the dynamic form with second form data. In the UI for first form i am getting exactly where in second form i am getting two select tags.

Comment: @user3355101 when you inspect elements for each of your divs, are they creating new indexes? Is `index` being grown  at all?

Comment: Would advise including the script that creates your content. the only thing that makes sense is that there are more than 1 div with that ID.